# How to convert an array [aaa,bbb,ccc] to [[aaa],[bbb],[ccc]]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

I have:

```
var array1 = [[aaa],[bbb]]; //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:A').getValues();
var array2 = [[ccc],[vvv],[fff]]; //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2:B').getValues();
```

Then i concatenate arrays:

```
const newArray = [];

array1.forEach( function(item1) {
  array2.forEach( function(item2) {
    newArray.push(item1 + " " + item2)
  })
});
```

Result of this function:

```
Logger.log(newArray);
//[aaa ccc, aaa vvv, aaa fff, bbb ccc, bbb vvv, bbb fff]
```

How can I convert the result to the next?

```
[[aaa ccc], [aaa vvv], [aaa fff], [bbb ccc], [bbb vvv], [bbb fff]]
```

I need this to put values ​​in a column:

```
sheet.getRange('D2:D').setValues(newArray)
```

Otherwise, an error is displayed: Unable to convert Array to number [][]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push a array instead:

```js
var array1 = [["aaa"],["bbb"]]; //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:A').getValues();
var array2 = [["ccc"],["vvv"],["fff"]]; //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2:B').getValues();


const newArray = [];

array1.forEach( function(item1) {
  array2.forEach( function(item2) {
    newArray.push([item1 + " " + item2])
  })
});
console.log(newArray)
```